# How to add properties to user control in Windows Phone

Tags: properties, windows-phone-8, controls, windows-phone

So i'm creating this app, where i have created my own user controls, and each of the controls has things that will be updated with information from the web, but i dont know how i can add properties to it. Like the name of that specific control. Like where are the height settings for instance stored in the control? In the code? Like this

mycontrol:

```
String nameofthiscontrol = "control";
```

and main code:

```
mycontrol mycontrol = new mycontrol();
mycontrol.nameofthiscontrol = "control1";
```

Is that how it works? I really need some guiding on this one, please help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

If you are talking about UserControl, it will have some basic properties common to all controls(like Width, Height, Background and such). You add properties like you would add anywhere else - within your UserControl.

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
    public MyControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //simple property
    public DesiredType PropertyName { get; set; }

    //dependancy property
    public DesiredType MyProperty
    {
        get { return (DesiredType)GetValue(MyPropertyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyProperty", typeof(DesiredType), typeof(ownerclass), new PropertyMetadata(0));
}
```

Both are useful(and must be public), but [DependencyProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221408%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) is better for bindings in MVVM.

Comment: i dont quite understand the code, could you please explain it a little deeper?

Comment: Property is basically a wrapper for get and set methods(and sometimes a variable like in my first example). You write this and call it as any other existing property. If you need to bind it and for something to happen when a value changes then use DependencyProperty where you can define callback method. Here is more about the [difference between DependancyProperty and Property](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cstein/archive/2008/10/29/normal-properties-vs-dependency-properties.aspx).